# python multiprocessing dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiprocessing

```
  def main():     
    df_master = read_bb_csv(file)
                p = Pool(2)
                if len(df_master.index) >= 1:
                    for row in df_master.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
                         p.map((partial(check_option, arg1=row), df_master))
    
    
    def check_option(row):
       get_price(row)
```

I am using Pandas to read a CSV, to loop through rows and process the informaiton. Give the function get_price() need to make serveral http calls, I want to use multiprocess to process all rows at once (depends on the CPU cores) to speed up the function.

The issue I am having is that, I am new to multi process and don't know how to use
**p.map((check_option, arg1=row), df_master)** to process all rows in the dataframe.
There is no need to return the **row** value back to the function. Just need to allow to rows to processes to handle.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if speed is the issue, before trying to multiprocess, try to make your code vectorial and not using loops

Comment: do you have any suggestions for this? I have used filter on DF before the for-loop. Based on the cprofile result. the http communication in the get_price() takes 80% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following python3 version that I use everywhere and it works like a charm! There's also a python3 package `mpire` which I found really useful and usage is similar to that of python3's multiprocessing package.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

def get_price(idx, row):
    # logic to fetch price
    return idx, price

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv("path to file")
    NUM_OF_WORKERS = 2 
    with Pool(NUM_OF_WORKERS) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(get_price, [idx, row]) for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
        for result in results:
            idx, price = result.get()
            df.loc[idx, 'Price'] = price
    # do whatever you want to do with df, save it to same file.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # don't forget to call main func as module
    # This is must in windows use multiple processes/threads. It's also a good practice, more info on this page https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!  I am getting error ' local variable 'idx' referenced before assignment' Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: there was a typo in line `results=`, I corrected it in the edit.